# Java Socket.bind(null);

Tags: java, sockets

According to the documentation passing null to the `Socket.bind()` method will cause system to automatically assign an ephemeral port number to the socket.

Whenever I try to do it, I am getting `"SocketException: Already Bound"`.

I tried reading into documentation, but being new to programming I don't fully understand everything that's there yet. Isn't `Socket.bind(null)` supposed to find an available port?

Also if I am being daft and following bad practices anywhere else in the code you are welcome to scorn me.

Below is the fragment of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket ss = null;

    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Listening on port " + ss.getLocalPort());
    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        socket = ss.accept();
        socket.bind(null); // crashes here

        Thread connection = new Thread(new Echo(socket));
        connection.run();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `socket.bind(null);` even when `8080` was successfully bound. You need to take it that code to a catch block.

Comment: Why are you trying to bind an accepted socket? It's already bound, by the action of `accept()`. Solution: don't.

Comment: Thank you both for replying. Should I use the same port number for all my threads?

Comment: Eh? You've been told not to do a bind at all. So you don't get to control the port number. You get whatever `accept()` gives you ... which as a matter of fact already is a socket bound to the same port number each time. BTW you should call `Thread.start()`, not `Thread.run()`. I have no idea what @ernest_k's comment is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

The call `socket.bind(null)` is wrong. The program may work without it if there are no other bugs for example in the Echo class. Just remove the line and try.

The socket `ss` is a server socket. It is bound to local port 8080. It does not represent any specific client connection. It just listens on the port 8080 and when a new client connects to the server then the accept returns a new socket that represents a client connection.

The socket `socket` is returned from accept and it represents the connection between server and the client. It is already bound to port 8080 when it is returned from the accept. So binding it again is both futile and wrong.

Basically the socket `socket` is associated with client's ip/port and server's ip/port. The foursome represent a unique connection. The socket `socket` can be used for sending and receiving data over the connection and it should be closed when client disconnects.